# Read value from one thread in Python: queue or global variable?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, global

I have a thread which every 10ms measures an voltage value (captured from an external device), applies some elementary low-pass filtering and stores the value in a variable `lp_voltage`. Every few seconds the main program needs to read the value stored in `lp_voltage`.

I have figured out two methods to possibly do that with the `threading` framework:

- [Sharing the global variable `lp_voltage` between the thread and the main program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790570/python-global-variable-with-thread), using the `global` keyword in the thread. This has the inconvenient of having to use global varialbles, which are [often considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil).
- [Using the Queue module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), which looks more *pythonic*. However I don't know how to adapt it for my problem: the main program only needs to access to the instantaneous value of the `lp_voltage` from time to time, and not to a full queue of data.

What option is best? If queues are better, how to adapt them to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First method is OK if you know what you are doing.

More explanation:

In both method, you need to make sure your two threads have access to a shared variable(`lp_voltage` or `v_queue`). What the real advantage `v_queue` has is consistence. If you don't care about consistence, you can just simply use a variable.

To implement this more pythonic, you can wrap your whole project into an `object`. For example:

```
class VoltageTask:

    def __init__(self):
        self.lp_voltage = 0
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update_voltage)

    def update_voltage(self):
        self.lp_voltage = your_function_to_get_voltage()

    def main_thread(self):
        ...

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()
        self.main_thread()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    task = VoltageTask()
    task.start()
```

Comment: I ended up using a solution like the one you propose, and it worked fine. The only difference is that took the main code I out of the class, and instead called read `lp_voltage` property of the `task` object.