# Why are threads not completing execution in Python? Semaphores are providing process synchronization but execution is not getting completed

Tags: python, multithreading, process, semaphore, thread-synchronization

The provided code is about `2 thread` trying to access the function `increment()` to increment the value of a `global variable` x. I have designed a `semaphore class` for process synchronization. So the expected increment of each thread is expected to be `1000000` summing up to `2000000`. But actual output is not reaching up to `2000000`. The output is reaching up to `1800000 - 1950000`. Why are all loop not executing?

```
import threading as th

x=0

class Semaphore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__s = 1
    def wait(self):
        while(self.__s==0):
            pass
        self.__s-=1

    def signal(self):
        self.__s+=1

def increment(s):
    global x
    s.wait()
    x+=1
    s.signal()

def task1(s):
    for _ in range(1000000):
        increment(s)

def task2(s):
    for _ in range(1000000):
        increment(s)

def main():
    s = Semaphore()
    t1 = th.Thread(target=task1,name="t1",args=(s,))
    t2 = th.Thread(target=task2,name="t1",args=(s,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    #Checking Synchronization
    for _ in range(10):
        print("Value of X: %d"%x)
    
    #waiting for termination of thread
    t2.join()
    t1.join()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
    print("X = %d"%x) #Final Output
```

Output:

```
Value of X: 5939
Value of X: 14150
Value of X: 25036
Value of X: 50490
Value of X: 54136
Value of X: 57674
Value of X: 69994
Value of X: 84912
Value of X: 94284
Value of X: 105895
X = 1801436
```

Answer (score 0):

The threads are working fine and they're completing correctly. It's your 'z' variable that's the problem.

In general using a global variable as a container for your shared memory between two threads is a bad way to go about it.

[Check out this answer to see why.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19790994/9902026)

I made the following changes to your code. I made 'z' the shared variable and 'x' and 'y' are data for each thread alone.

```
x=0
y=0
z=0

def increment1(s):
    global x,z
    s.wait()
    x+=1
    z+=1
    s.signal()

def increment2(s):
    global y,z
    s.wait()
    y+=1
    z+=1
    s.signal()

def task1(s):
    for somei in range(1000000):
        increment1(s)

def task2(s):
    for somej in range(1000000):
        increment2(s)
```

This is the output I got:

```
X = 1000000
Y = 1000000
Z = 1961404
```

As you can see there's nothing wrong with the threads themselves, as they're completing their execution. But the shared data Z is a little wonky. Z will change randomly each time you run the script. Hence as you can see using global variables as shared memory is a bad idea.

A much better option would be using some python supported sharing tool such as Queue provided by python's library itself. It's a multi-producer, multi-consumer message queue and helps when it comes to shared data such as the data you're using now.

Let me show you how it can be done with Queue:

```
import threading as th
from Queue import Queue

def task1(q):
    global x,z
    for somei in range(1000000):
        q.put(q.get() + 1)

def task2(q):
    global y,z
    for somei in range(1000000):
        q.put(q.get() + 1)

def main():
    queue = Queue()
    queue.put(0)
    t1 = th.Thread(target=task1,name="t1",args=(queue, ))
    t2 = th.Thread(target=task2,name="t1",args=(queue, ))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    #Checking Synchronization

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    return queue.get()

if __name__=="__main__":
    print("Queue = %d"%main()) #Final Output
```

You don't even need to create a semaphore here as the Queue will automatically take care of synchronization.

The output of this final program is this:

```
Queue = 2000000
```