# Python global variable shared between threads (using python-osc)

Tags: python, global, python-multithreading, osc

I'm stuck with a threading problem here. I need threads to access a global variable.

I've read a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790570/python-global-variable-with-thread#19790803) to a similar question and I understood the "power" of the **global** keyword in order for functions and threads to access to global variables.

I'm able to make the following code work and it is pretty straightforward to me:

```
# WORKING CODE !!!

from threading import Thread
import sys, time

a = "" #global variable

def thread1(threadname):
    global a
    while True:
        a *= 2
        time.sleep(2)

def thread2(threadname):
    global a
    while True:
        a += 1
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread1 = Thread( target=thread1, args=("Thread-1", ) )
    thread2 = Thread( target=thread2, args=("Thread-2", ) )

    a = 23

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    while True:
        print(a)
```

Now I would like to have an OSC driven function to modify the global variable *a*.
I'm using the [python-osc](https://github.com/attwad/python-osc) module and I'm making the OSC server running on its own thread.
As before I have declared *a* as a global variable inside the *mapped* function associated with the "*/learn*" OSC method.

Strangely to my comprehension the following code is not behaving the same way as the previous one.

**edited 2018-10-18, 16:14**: "*a*" is not increasing at all and what I'm seeing printed is

```
a: 1
```

printed continuosly. As if we had two different *"a*" values: one that is increasing inside the OSC thread which is different from the global "*a*" of the main one.

What I doing wrong?

```
import threading
from time import sleep
from pythonosc import osc_server, dispatcher

OSCaddress = "192.168.1.68"
OSCport    = 13000

a = ""

# OSC functions
def menageLearnButton(unused_addr, args, value):
    global a
    if value == 1:
        a += 1
    else:
        a += 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # OSC dispatcher to respond to incoming OSC messages
    dispatcher = dispatcher.Dispatcher()
    dispatcher.map("/learn", menageLearnButton, "learning")

    a = 1

    # better to run the OSC server on its own thread
    # in order not to block the program here
    OSCserver = osc_server.ForkingOSCUDPServer((OSCaddress, OSCport), dispatcher)
    OSCserver_thread = threading.Thread(target=OSCserver.serve_forever)
    OSCserver_thread.start()

    while True:
        print("a: {}".format(a))
        sleep(1)
```

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Are you sure `value` does have the value that you expect?

Comment: Hi @astorga, yes. On some previous tests I've made i've placed a print inside the `menageLearnButton` to make this exact same check. 
However, here there's also an `else` statement which should increment the `a` variable regardless of the value of the `value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what is going on is that 'ForkingOSCUDPServer' is creating a new process for each OSC request so 'a' is getting reinitialized each time.  If I switch your code to use 'ThreadingOSCUDPServer' it seems to have the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you @RawBengal, you are right!
Thank you for your precious support and excuse me form my late reply :)

Comment: Thank you both for your great question and answer. Helped me solve the same issue! :)