# How to share session values created outside the context in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

How do I store something created by a thread, in a session, so I can access that value later in another request?

Here is a sample:

```py
@app.route('/one')
def one():
    @copy_current_request_context
    def x():
        session['status'] = "done"      

    t = threading.Thread(target=x)
    t.start()
    return "One"



@app.route('/two')
def two():
    status = session['status']
    return "Two: {}".format(status)
```

In example above I store the 'status' from within the thread (I need to run the thread) inside the /one request but later, let's say 5s, I want to check for the status in another request (/two).

Also does @copy_current_request_context make a read-only (or read and discard write) copy of the session/request?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and somehow best answer is using global variables that have been described completely [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790570/using-a-global-variable-with-a-thread).

But if your application is going to be scaled and you need this data to be shared with other instances, you might use "Redis" as a fast In-Memory DB. [More details](http://redis.io)

Answer (score 1):

1. By using the suggestion from @soroosh-khodami I was able to achieve what I wanted. Bellow is the code that can do that.

```py
warehouse = {} # This associative array will keep the data

@app.route('/one')
def one():
    global warehouse
    @copy_current_request_context
    def x():
        warehouse['status'] = "done"      

    t = threading.Thread(target=x)
    t.start()
    return "One"



@app.route('/two')
def two():
    global warehouse
    status = warehouse['status']
    return "Two: {}".format(status)
```

Of course this is a naive implementation - as this object **warehouse** will be shared among all the requests and session - so a protection mechanism should be in place (Ex: 1.Store all things from a session under a certain key 2. Have a cleanup thread , etc)

**Bonus**: The addition to that is that is working even in non-dev environment (ex: Twisted server)

2. Yes, *@copy_current_request_context* makes a read only copy of the context (as far as I tested)