# Question about data exchange between threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to make a motor control system using Object Detection. I have two threads, one for object detection and one for GUI.

Here is the code for object detection

```
#execute object detection model in real time
def tfod_window():
    global coordinates, class_name, named_coordinates

    category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(files['LABELMAP'])


    while cap.isOpened(): 
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        image_np = np.array(frame)
        
        input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
        detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
        
        num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
        detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                      for key, value in detections.items()}
        detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

        # detection_classes should be ints.
        detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

        label_id_offset = 1
        image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

        viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                    image_np_with_detections,
                    detections['detection_boxes'],
                    detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                    detections['detection_scores'],
                    category_index,
                    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                    max_boxes_to_draw=5,
                    min_score_thresh=.8,
                    agnostic_mode=False)

        cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))

        #get the coordinates of the detection boxes
        boxes = detections['detection_boxes']
        max_boxes_to_draw = boxes.shape[0]
        scores = detections['detection_scores']
        min_score_thresh=.8

        coordinates=[]
        class_name=[]
        named_coordinates=[]

        for i in range(min(max_boxes_to_draw, boxes.shape[0])):
            if scores[i] > min_score_thresh:
                class_id = int(detections['detection_classes'][i] + 1)
                coordinates.append(boxes[i])
                class_name.append(category_index[class_id]["name"])
                named_coordinates.append({
                                "box": boxes[i],
                                "class_name": category_index[class_id]["name"],
                            })

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cap.release()      
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

However when I want to use coordinates in another thread, it shows '''NameError: name 'class_name' is not defined'''.

The code for another thread is

```
def GUI():
    while cap.isOpened():
        if len(class_name) > 0:
            print(class_name)

t1 = Thread(target=tfod)
t2 = Thread(target=GUI)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Please Help!! Thank you!!

Comment: where is `class_name` declared and initialized

Comment: `class_name` is under the `#get the coordinates of the detection boxes` part of the first code.

Comment: you should define it outside of the method, before either function gets called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: `class_name` was not declared/initialized before the `t2` thread tried to access it.

You can place a single initial line of code defining `class_name` near the top of the program, and this will avoid this error.

For those who may see this page, the error is not super relevant to the title,  but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790570/using-a-global-variable-with-a-thread) is a post that does discuss how to properly share data between threads.